# How do i create a fully dynamic databinding in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-binding, proxy, handler

My goal is to implement something similar to the **.NETs BindingList.** To start simple I thought beginning with a 'BindingObject' would be much simpler.

Whenever a property of my object gets **changed/created/removed** I want to throw an event or call a function. In the end i want to be able to react to each property of an object dynamically.

I've read several articles on how to approach this. Most advice using JavaScript Proxys.

This is what ive tried for now:

```
var handler = {
    get: function (target, propname) {
        console.log('get');
        return target[propname];
    }};

BindingObject.prototype.constructor = new Proxy({}, handler);

function BindingObject(object) {
    //access handler here
}
```

Of course i want to have a handler for each object created and not the same handler for every object. Also I would love to pass the proxyobject and handler in the constructor which I can't get to work either.

This is my second try which allows passing my object in constructor but I am not able to access my handler:

```
class BindingObject2 {
    constructor(obj) {
        this.handler = {
            get: function (target, propname) {
                console.log('get');
                return target[propname];
            }};
        return new Proxy(obj || {}, this.handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class based approach does not meet all of the OP's requirements. The provided example code already makes that obvious. There is a constructor that creates a type with a `handler` property but does not return it, instead the constructor returns a proxy object.

A good old factory function might be the better choice ...

```js
function createComposedProxyType(trapHandlerOptions, type) {
  var proxy = new Proxy((type || {}), trapHandlerOptions);
  proxy.__traps__ = trapHandlerOptions;
  return proxy;
}

function handlePropertyChange(target, key, value/*, receiver*/) {
  console.log("handlePropertyChange :: [key, value] :", key, value);
  target[key] = value;
  return true;
}

var trapConfig = {
  set: handlePropertyChange
};

var type = createComposedProxyType(trapConfig);

console.log('type : ', type);

type.foo = 'foo';
type.bar = 'bar';

console.log('type : ', type);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: havn't tried it yet, but looks nice so far. Ty very much!

Answer (score 0):

It would be problematic to use just databinding in JS. It could be a part of the popular framework: angular, aurelia or react (sort of... +redux that is about to be dead).

With jQuery it would need to manually wire up all prop changes. Probably implement some Observer/Subscriber approach.

Or use some component for databinding tasks that provides enough convenient databinding definition commands. I did it with databindjs. e.g.

```
// Lets assume that there is just simple form (target)
var simpleForm = {
   input: $('.simple .input-value'),
   output: $('.simple .output-value')
};
// And here is the simple model object (source)
var model = {
    text: 'initial value'
};

// Lets set two directional binding between [input] <-> [text]
var simpleBinding = bindTo(simpleForm, () => model, {
    'input.val': 'text',  // bind to user input
    'output.text': 'text'  // simple region that will react on user input
});
// This command will sync values from source to target (from model to view)
updateLayout(simpleBinding);
subscribeToChange(simpleBinding, () => {
    $('.simple .console').html(JSON.stringify(model));
});
// Just initialize console from default model state
$('.simple .console').html(JSON.stringify(model));
```

The full solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rsjpa0o8/5/).
You can check the full implementation of the databinding core [on github](https://github.com/vkopytin/databinding/blob/master/src/databindjs/core.ts)